# Sending a POST request using Balkan's requests lib with data and files (Robot Framework)

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to send a request (post) using Balkan's requests library from test case written in Robot Framework http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/#Post with two parameters as a data and a file. Unfortunatelly, all the time I have the same error like described below.

My Test Case:

```
X_T_Should Upload File Correctly And Get HTTP 200
    Send Default File To SUT And Return Response

*** Keywords ***
Send Default File To SUT And Return Response
    [Arguments]    ${user_login}=${USER_LOGIN}    ${user_password}=${USER_PASSWORD}
    ${url}=    Get URL
    ${auth}=    Create List    ${user_login}    ${user_password}
    Create Session    rm    ${url}    auth=${auth}
    &{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    &{data}=    Create Dictionary    name=file    filename=${DEFAULT_FILE_NAME}
    ${file_data}=    Get Binary File    ${CURDIR}${/}Resources${/}${DEFAULT_FILE_NAME}
    &{files}=    Create Dictionary    file=${file_data}
    ${resp}=    Post Request    rm    ${UPLOAD_URI}    files=${files}    data=${data}    headers=${headers}
    Delete All Sessions
```

Error (from Robot Framework):

```
20160525 09:47:10.645 :  FAIL : ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

The problem is with the keyword Post Request. When I do not set an argument files or data that everything is well but if I set both args. that I see these strange error.

It is a bug in library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `files` parameter is a list of file *names*. You are passing the actual file contents into the keyword. This might explain why you are getting "Data must not be a string".

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Finally, I wrote a keyword in python. It is more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was correct in 2016, but the documentation actually says "`files` a dictionary of file names containing file data to POST to the server", thus providing a dictionary should be correct? http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/#Post%20Request

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered this exception also. The exception seems to be raised in Requests Python library.
At [line 119 of `requests/models.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/9407d697c8842fa7e15572ab77f1b0592544e02b/requests/models.py#L119),

```
elif isinstance(data, basestring)
```

checks whether `data` is a string. And robotframework-requests [seems](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/src/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py#L415) to be casting `data` into a string almost always. There is an [issue](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/issues/131) for robotframework-requests regarding the exception.